# Kotlin yield function not co-operative in cancelling the co-routine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Unlike emit() function inside the FlowCollector, yield function does not co-operate when cancelling the co-routine. Below is the example program :-

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlinx.coroutines.withTimeoutOrNull

fun main(): Unit = runBlocking {
    withTimeoutOrNull(5000) {
        getFlow().collect { println("printing flow iteration $it on ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
    }

    withTimeoutOrNull(5000) {
        getSequence().forEach { println("printing sequence iteration $it on ${Thread.currentThread().name}") }
    }
}

fun getSequence() = sequence<Int> {
    for (i in 1..10) {
        wasteCpuCycles(1000)
        yield(i)
    }
}

fun getFlow() = flow<Int> {
    for (i in 1..10) {
        wasteCpuCycles(1000)
        emit(i)
    }
}

fun wasteCpuCycles(durationInMillis: Int) {
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + durationInMillis
    while (endTime >= System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    }
}
```

Below is the output of the execution:-

printing flow iteration 1 on main
printing flow iteration 2 on main
printing flow iteration 3 on main
printing flow iteration 4 on main
printing sequence iteration 1 on main
printing sequence iteration 2 on main
printing sequence iteration 3 on main
printing sequence iteration 4 on main
printing sequence iteration 5 on main
printing sequence iteration 6 on main
printing sequence iteration 7 on main
printing sequence iteration 8 on main
printing sequence iteration 9 on main
printing sequence iteration 10 on main

As per the signature of both yield and emit functions i expected that both participate in co-operative cancellation of the co-routine. But by looking at the output it can be found yield does not stop even when the co-routine is cancelled from timeout. As both are suspending functions, What can be the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: Not all suspending functions are cancellable - they need to intentionally support being cancelled. Still, I'm surprised `yield()` isn't. Maybe this is somehow related to the fact that `yield()` isn't a part of coroutines package, maybe it does not have access to some intrinsics (?). Also, note that there are two distinct `yield()` functions. One that is used to generate sequences (`SequenceScope.yield()`) and another (just `yield()`) which supports cancelling.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike flow, sequences are not asynchronous. So yield function inside SequenceScope is not cancellable and have no effect on the state of co-routine being run.

Answer (score 0):

Note that neither `sequence { }` function nor `next()` is suspendable, they also don't receive a coroutine context/scope. I guess that means the coroutine that runs inside a sequence is not attached to the coroutine context of the caller, it does not take part in its structured concurrency. As a result, even if `withTimeoutOrNull()` cancells a coroutine running inside it, the coroutine inside `sequence { }` is detached from above and isn't notified about the cancellation.

At least this is my understanding, I may miss something.